# iOS push view onto stack in a tabbar application

Tags: ios, view, push, tabbar

I am making a tabbar application I have an email button and would like when touched it pushes and email form ontop of the stack. Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To push a view, you need a `UINavigationController`.

Check out the [MFMailComposeViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and download the `MailComposer` example.